# Disable Firestore in native mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, datastore

I think that in my project cloud firestore was wrongly enabled in native mode, while I would like to use the "old" datastore or firebase in native mode.

I don't have a way create the project again, is there a way to revert and don't use firestore in native mode ?

In my services list I've already disabled firestore with the command

```
gcloud services disable firestore.googleapis.com
```

but still when I go to the datastore page I'm redirected to "You are using firestore in native mode, go to the firestore page".

This is odd because the application continues to run in the meantime, but the data in firestore is "empty", so I think that my application is using the datastore, but I'm unable to get to the data via gcp console.

Is there any way I can fix this without deleting the project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there's no way.

I think you can try and reach support, I had to ditch the project.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore databases without any data in them can be switched between either mode (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#changing_between_native_mode_and_datastore_mode).